# NHibernate 1st Level Cache when Item is added to a HasMany Collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching, fluent-nhibernate

I am creating a new object by adding to to a HasMany collection on ANOTHER object in NHibernate.

When I go to query for that object directly in the same session, it is null. How can I store a child object in a HasMany collection in the 1st level cache. The problem I am having is I need to get the object and do some work on it before everything is committed.

```
 HasMany(x => x.BehavioralEvents)
     .AsBag()
     .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
     .Inverse()
     .KeyColumn("StudentCaseId")
     .LazyLoad();
```

BehavioralEvents is an IList and I need to Query for it directly in the same session:

```
session.Get<BehavioralEvent>(id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Save the new object to make it persistent instead of relying on the cascade settings from the parent object. The cascade will not occur until the session is flushed. I assume you are assigning the ID yourself and not using a generated identifier.

Comment: Yes, I am assigning the ID myself. So just make a call to session.save then add my object to the collection?